# Getting an error Adobe AIR version not installed error

Tags: android, air, flash-builder

I'm getting an error when trying to debug my AIR app on Android, "Device appears to be offline". It used to work. I have AIR installed. I'm not sure what changed. I think maybe AIR was updated and that changed something but I'm guessing.

I've attached an image.

[image]

I've restarted the device a few times. I'm using Flash Builder 4.7. I have AIR 3.6.0.597 installed. USB Debugging is enabled. It's also connected as a Media device (MTP) which I may have accidentally turned on (but I'm not sure and it doesn't seem there's a way to turn this off).

Comment: Which device? What happens when you click "I don't see my connected device in the list"? Have you rebooted your device?

Comment: It's a Nexus 7. I found the cause of the issue and about to post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's how I got *debugging* to work for the following.

I'm using Mac OSX 10.8.2, Nexus 7, Flash Builder 4.7 and AIR: 3.6.

1. Download the latest Android SDK here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
2. Unzip it and copy aapt, adb and dx.jar from the [android-sdk]\platform-tools\ directory (dx.jar is in the \platform-tools\lib directory).
3. Paste these files in the [FLEX_SDK_AIR_3.6]\lib\android\bin directory.
4. Restart Flash Builder

I think the dx.jar is necessary when creating the release build.

There's another issue that may be related, [Error SDK component at air/android/device/runtime.apk is out of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061151/error-sdk-component-at-air-android-device-runtime-apk-is-out-of-date). Still trying to figure this one out.

Answer (score 5):

I also recently updated to Jelly Bean 4.2.2 and now Flash Builder shows the same thing.

Adobe AIR Version: Not installed
State: Offline

OS: Windows 8.
Device: Nexus 7.
IDE: Flash Builder 4.6.
AIR: 3.4.

As mention above by 1.21 gigawatts pointed out [a link](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5086305) that goes to a thread with this suggestion:

> Same boat,  from
>   \android-sdk\platform-tools   copy theses
>   files : aapt.exe, adb.exe, AdbWinApi.dll, AdbWinUsbApi.dll and dx.jar
>   (under lib rep)   and paste into \lib\android\bin
>   To check, tape in cmd   $ adb.exe version, you should have 1.0.31
>   instead of 1.0.26   Voilà!

The fresh updated sdk can be found here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download

Going to see if the sdk update helps at all.  Will report back "shortly".

[UPDATE]
Works for me! Thanks for posting [that link](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5086305) 1.21 gigawatts. Yep, the problem is the [new RSA key needed for the device to communicate with your computer](http://www.androidcentral.com/semi-pro-tip-android-422-here-your-android-sdk-might-need-updating).

I copied files listed above into the the flex air sdk.  You need to confirm communication with your computer on your Nexus 7.  There is a little popup prompt asking if you want to allow communication with the computer.  After confirming refresh the device list; the device will show up correctly and you can get back to life as normal.

To those what would downvote the original question just because all the information was not supplied I have following to say.  I found what I needed without every little detail included in the question.  Questions do not need to be perfect and simple "cookie crumbs" are useful.  *sigh*  I wonder how much useful information is lost because of this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not able to find aapt after downloading the sdk from the link given, you need to go to Terminal and from the "tools" folder type:
./android update sdk
Then check build-tools
Also, for me it still didnt work until I updated Adobe AIR SDK to latest (using rsync not regular copy), and finally copy android-sdk-mac_x86/platforms/android-xx/android.jar to [air-sdk-version]/lib/android/lib/android-res.jar