# Error SDK component at air/android/device/runtime.apk is out of date

Tags: android, air, flash-builder

I'm getting the following error when packaging AIR application.

```
Error occurred while packaging the application:

SDK component at air/android/device/Runtime.apk is out of date.
```

[image]

This occurs on the last step when creating a release build.

Comment: I'm using AIR SDK 3.6.

Comment: you must be targeting the wrong one or you're not forcing an update to the SDK on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue is but it only happens sometimes but if I wait or if I try again it works. Maybe Flash Builder refreshes on a cycle and I'm running it too often or if I wait too long between moving through the steps it's expiring? I'll post back when I know more.

**UPDATE**
If you create a release build and then you go get a cup of coffee and then come back it won't work. If you stay and don't get coffee and hit the next button after the compiling step is done then it works. It is not compatible with the coffee.

Comment: @gigawatts Do you find the real reason now? My build machine suffers this error too.

Comment: This happened a few more times. I think you have to go through the steps quickly and not wait. There are two steps. If you wait too long between them (not pressing the next button right away) it doesn't seem to work. Try it again and let me know if you can get it to work if you move quickly to the next step.

Comment: I have the same issue when I build my project with ANT. After compiling I go to packaging for Android as the immediate next step, but my project packages several versions of the same app (with some different settings inside). Usually the first few package calls succeed, but the third or fourth package call often fails (not always though). I'd really like to know the REAL cause of this error. My ANT script doesn't go get any coffee in between ;)

Comment: I did a bit of research, this is probably fixed in AIR SDK 3.8 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492157/whats-causing-this-error-sdk-component-at-air-android-device-runtime-apk-is-o/17496928#17496928

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the root cause of this problem, but updating my AIRSDK to 3.8 beta helped.

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashruntimes/air/