# nexus 7 with flash builder Error adobe air version not installed state offline

Tags: android, flash, flash-builder

I've done a bit of research since my previous question was not considered question. I have nexus 7 to use it with Flash Builder 4.6.

I initially downloaded Android SDK and installed the Google USB driver. I turned on the debugging option for my nexus, and I also made `USB computer connection` to PTP connection.

Finally, I run an app from Flash Builder I get the following screen:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSkXs.png]

I try to uninstall adobe air and re-install but it didn't work. Please, I need your help. My laptop is windows 7 OS. I also run command line and checked my `platform-tools` and run  `adb devices`.

It recognizes my nexus is attached with its serial number and ‘device’ word. One more thing, the nexus connection also show the device is charging.

Comment: Have you seen this? [`Adobe AIR version not installed error`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15036611/1693859)

Comment: yes, I have seen it. Mine is windows, but I went to Flash builder sdks then I have two version one AIR 3.6.0 has no android folder as described by that link, then I opened lib android directory on AIR 4.6.0 version I still get the same thing

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue.  As user user1986244 said, I had to do some moving around of executables.
I placed all the .EXEs (adb.exe and others) as mentioned into the 
`<FlashBuilderDir>\sdks\4.6.0\lib\android\bin` folder, but, I also had to place them here:

```
<FlashBuilderDir>\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722\AIRSDK\lib\android\bin
```

It then asked me to install the AIRSDK and my application began working.

I'm assuming there is a more elegant solution here, but, I've yet to find it.

Answer (score 2):

For two days, I try to find solution. Finally worked. I want to go through the steps. After installing android sdk that comes with ADT bundle. Running sdk manager. Check Tools and google usb driver from options list. My device is nexus seven. Then I installed Flash builder 4.6. I created simple Hello program, and run. But gave me screen 'adobe air not installed' and state 'offline', as I mentioned in my initial question above.
      Next, I read a post from adobe forum help, that says copy adb.exe from android ADT folde and paste it to flash builder. My actual path goes like this in the ADT folder sdk/platform-tools/adb. So I copy adb and went to Adobe flash builder 4.6 folder/sdks/4.6.0/lib/android/bin. In this folder i pasted what I copied, pop up message says you cant paste it is open. Instead of making it skip. I ctrl + alt + delete and close adb.exe from applications. Now, I went back and clicked try again. It pasted it
     Next run my android test, it asked me 'would you like to install adobe air?' on your device. I clicked yes, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to install drivers manually 
http://fr.asus.com/Tablet/Nexus/Nexus_7/#download

Then allow usb debugg on your device

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did usb driver with the android ADT, then also did from ASUS offical site. Nothing working. When i use Eclipse I can debug. Not with flash builder. I am new to android and development. Second day, still getting me frustrated and I cant stop trying to fix it. Help!!

Comment: What is the version of your android ? if it's 4.2.2
you have to update aapt adb and dx.jar

i ran the same issue with my nexus 4 and updating my android sdk and installing usb driver solve my problem :)

last thing you have to activate usb debugging on your device.


http://www.aymericlamboley.fr/blog/android-4-2-2-resolve-problem-with-air-mobile-deployment/

Comment: 4.2.2 and i only updated my adb file. worked. Mine was nexus 7

Answer (score 0):

Like LordJalek said, I had to copy adb to these two folders. If those folders does not exists locate them from Flash Builder preferences. Then I was neccessary to restart adb:

> adb stop-server
>
> adb start-server

Then when I clicked on refresh on the "Choose Device" screen it worked and now I see my device online.